# How to use images in “Select List” oracle apex?

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a country table , with three column country code and country name and country phone code , and static file for all country flag also.
All flag image name  same a country code in table ,how I can create a select list to Display  country flag CONCATENATION with country name .

Comment: What version of APEX are you using?

Comment: Apex 19.2 version

Comment: Ok,thank you I will try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went to [apex.world](https://apex.world) and found this plug-in from Alan Arentsen that seems to fit the bill: https://apex.world/ords/f?p=100:710:::::P710_PLG_ID:COM.ADBC.APEX.JET.OJSELECTCOMBOBOX However, it doesn't currently support APEX 19.1+. If you don't mind experimenting a little, you could update the JS file in the plug-in (once installed) using the code I submitted in this PR: https://github.com/alanarentsen/plugin-apex-jet-ojselectcombobox/pull/6 Or you could wait until he's able to get a new version out, though I can't say how long that would take.

Another option would be to use the popup LOV and then modify the template using JavaScript to allow it to display images. If you take the plug-in or Popup LOV path and need more details, let me know and I'll provide them.