# Oracle Apex - Change image item based on select list value

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Is it possible to Change image item based on select list value in Oracle Apex 19 ?

I have a select list of countries and I want to show an image of each country selected in the select list.

And thank you in advance

Comment: Are you currently showing any images? If yes, how so?

Comment: Also, what version of APEX are you on and have you seen this plug-in? It can show images in the select list: https://apex.world/ords/f?p=100:710:::::P710_PLG_ID:COM.ADBC.APEX.JET.OJSELECTCOMBOBOX

Comment: the select list must have a value by default...and based on this value i'll show an image.
in fact, I want to show country flags based on the country's name in the select list.

Comment: Have you considered either of these posts? https://dickdral.blogspot.com/2016/05/flag-images-in-apex-reports-and-select.html https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59934901/how-to-use-images-in-select-list-oracle-apex

Comment: For the first link it works only in Firefox and for the second link it doesn't work for me because I have Oracle Apex version 19.2 and the this version does not support this plugin.

Comment: If you look in the notes of the second link, I wrote an updated JS file that you can use to get the plug-in working with APEX 19.2. Are you able to try that?

Comment: Yes it works...Thank you
Can I also add the image in the selected Item?